# Spark Column Renamed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am just trying to understand why the below "withColumnRenamed" function is not working.I  don't have a reason to do this but i am trying to understand why it fails:

```
val a = sqlContext.sql("msck repair table db_name.table_name")
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [result: string]
scala> a.show()
+------+
|result|
+------+
+------+


scala> a.printSchema
root
 |-- result: string (nullable = false)


    a.withColumnRenamed("result","res")
    org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) result#32 missing from result#22 in operator !Project [result#32 AS res#33];
```

But this works:

```
a.select($"result".as("res"))
```

I looked at the Plan and seems like its getting assigned a different unique column id for the same column at different stages of the plan,the unique id for a given column should be same across the plan ,correct?

```
a.explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
HiveNativeCommand msck repair table db_name.table_name
== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
result: string
HiveNativeCommand msck repair table db_name.table_name
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
HiveNativeCommand msck repair table db_name.table_name
== Physical Plan ==
ExecutedCommand HiveNativeCommand msck repair table db_name.table_name
scala> a.queryExecution.logical.output
res76: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Attribute] = List(result#140)
scala> a.queryExecution.analyzed.output
res77: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Attribute] = List(result#141)
scala> a.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.output
res78: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Attribute] = List(result#142)
```

I am using Spark 1.6

Comment: what does `a.show()` outputs?

Comment: Updated ,its returns empty since the hive metadata is already updated .

Comment: What is a result of `a.withColumnRenamed("result","res").explain(extended = true)`?

Comment: @T.Gawęda: It fails with the same error.I think it does not even reach the"explain" function part

Comment: @ftw Strange. When you open withColumnRenamed function, it basically do `col.as(other)`

Comment: @T.Gawęda : Is there a way i can access the "sqlContext.analyzer.resolver" ,seems like the analyzer object is protected,any workaround?

Comment: resolver is just `a == b` ;)